# Redirection from non www to www for category page is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using below code for removal of index.php and redirect non-www to www for my website. It is working perfectly for home page, but when I go for category pages, index.php is working fine but inner page redirection from non-www to www is not working. This is a wordpress website.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line makes the rewrite engine stop processing more rules:

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

That's what the `[L]` means.

Solution: put your www redirect first.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```